# Is this a good method to find hcf?

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
     int a,b,hcf=0,i=1;
     cout<<"Enter Value  :";
     cin>>a;

     cout<<"Enter value  :";
     cin>>b;

    while(i<=a || i<=b){
         if(a%i ==0 && b%i ==0)hcf=i;
         ++i;
        }        
 return 0;
    }
```

or Remainder Method ?

Comment: I cannot figure out what you're trying to do, or perhaps hcf does not mean "highest common factor"? What is the 10 doing in the code?

Comment: You do know that [HCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire) (Halt-and-Catch-Fire) is a joke machine code instruction and not a real one, right?

Comment: It's rather straightforward.. I'd say too straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Are you finding the hcf at all ? It looks like that you are trying to reverse a number.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the numbers involved are *really* small, Euclid's algorithm is likely to be a *lot* faster. This one is linear on the size of the number (with two divisions per iteration, and divisions are one of the slowest types of instruction). Euclid's is actually fairly non-trivial to analyze -- Knuth V2 has several pages on it, but the bottom line is that it's generally quite a bit faster.

If you want to use a variation on the one you're using now, I'd start with `i` equal to the smaller of the two inputs, and work your way *down*. This way, the *first* time you find a common factor, you have your answer so you can break out of the loop.